# Looking for a tool that merges output from different shells

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash script that spins off three processes like this:

```
CD FOO_DIR && ./run-foo
CD BAR_DIR && ./run-bar
CD BAZ_DIR && ./run-baz
```

I want a tool that splits the parent shell into three sections (horizontally or vertically -- there's no difference) and shows the output of each child process in each section respectively.

Does such a tool exist?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Can you use `screen(1)` and run each in a different tab? Or in different tabs in a terminal? A sneaky way of doing it would be to run several shells inside emacs in windows split vertically...

Answer (score 3):

As has been said, screen should suit your needs.

Create a screen configuration file that looks like this:

```
startupmessage off
split
split

screen -t top top                       # -t <title> <command>
screen -t netstat watch netstat -tanp 
screen -t date watch date 

select top # In the first screen show the screen titled 'top'

focus down # Focus down to next screen
select netstat # Show screen titled 'netstat'

focus down # Focus down to the next screen
select date # Show the screen titled date
```

Let's call this file `screen_run`. Then simply run screen. The -c option specifies the configuration file to use :

```
screen -c screen_run
```

If you want vertical splits, you should be able to use `split -v` in place of `split`.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/ for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `screen`, you may want to check out [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net) as well. Each has its strengths and weaknesses, and you may prefer one's handling of splits over the other's.